# Dojo - problem sending form with IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, dojo

I am getting a JavaScript error in IE6 when trying to send form data with xhrGet.  Here is the code:

```
var kw = {
    url: "Save.action",
    load: function(data){
    },
    error: function(data){
    },
    form: "editData"
};
dojo.xhrGet(kw);
```

It works fine in IE 8.  I am using Dojo 1.3.2 and the error in the uncompressed dojo.js is at line 8713.

Any suggesttions (other than "don't support IE6")?

Thanks

Comment: Run in a "source" version of Dojo in MS Visual Studio or using the old IE debugger, and you should be able to report a line of code that's failing, with uncompress var names, stack and exception info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a combination of two things: Dojo not liking IE6 and me not using the preferred call.  When I switched from xhrGet() to xhrPost() it works fine.

To answer the question above, my error was "invalid argument".   I still think this is a problem with Dojo but am happy to move on.